# Проблема с simplexml_load_string в Magento!

Tags: php, magento, simplexml

Восстановил дамп бд и клонировал проект Mageto1.9. Добавил свой `local.xml` в него внес нужные данные.

Но ничего не работает( При переходе на хост выбрасывает ошибку:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 10: parser error :
>   Start tag expected, '<' not found  in
>   /Users/user/Sites/project.dev/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 510

Гуглил очень долго - в основном пишут, что проблема с каким то leyout или файлом config.xml но толком решения никакого не нашел (все `layout` и `xml` файлы проверил - вроде все нормально)!

**Как можно это исправить ? Или возможно я что не так делаю ?**

Comment: версия php какая?

Comment: @Naumov, за 3 часа нашел решение проблеми ) просто в одном локальном модуле разработчик не правильно выделил комментарий в layout файле! Намучился  с этим (

Comment: Частая проблема на php7.0 если ставить magento 1.9 такая же проблема. Да и у меня было такое но там просто конфиг был закоментирован а одна строка изменена так и смержилось. Правда искал меньше, запускаешь под xdebug с точкой остановки где есть ошибка и проматываешь до шага где она возникает. Там видно фаил который битый.

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо) буду теперь знать )!

Comment: да незашто и вот ссылка на можуль совместимости с php7 https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7